# eval - How to skip $ character enclosed in single quotes from being evaluated

Tags: bash, tomcat, escaping, quotes

'-Dmyprop=abc$354' is getting evaluated to -Dmyprop=abc54 even though it is present in single quotes. Is there a way around this?

`eval exec '"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"' '"-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties"' -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager '-Dmyprop=abc$354' -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources '-Djava.endorsed.dirs="/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed"' -classpath '"/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar"' '-Dcatalina.base="/usr/local/tomcat"' '-Dcatalina.home="/usr/local/tomcat"' '-Djava.io.tmpdir="/usr/local/tomcat/temp"' org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`

`exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dmyprop=abc54 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start`

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all?

Comment: Do you really need an `eval` here?

Comment: The single quotes only exist until the shell has evaluated the arguments to `eval`; `eval` itself does not see them.

Comment: @chepner This snippet is from tomcat bin/catalina.sh. Can't change that

Answer (score 1):

short answer:
you have to escape it with \ and open/close ' add ""

single quotes are literal unlike doubles. example of escape:
close ', open ", clos ", open singles again. This way you can interpolate or escape what you need in a singles string. Its frustrating. here is an example:

```
    tempSample=$(awk  'BEGIN { rounded = sprintf("%.0f", '"$((size1/div))"'); print rounded }')
```